# Bootstrap Navigation - Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see the content stays out of the = box on mobile and when the page is rescaled

[image]

My current HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" title="Index" href="http://www.example.com">MP3Jungle</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" title="Singles" href="http://www.example.com/category/singles/">Singles</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" title="Singles" href="http://www.example.com/category/videos/">Videos</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" title="Singles" href="http://www.example.com/category/albums/">Albums</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" title="Singles" href="http://www.example.com/category/mixtapes/">Mixtapes</a>
</div>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" role="search">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</nav>
```

How can I get the content into the collapsed box? Thanks!

Comment: The icon is called a "hamburger menu" in the UI world.  Mmmm, hamburgers......

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap expects menu links to be a `<ul>` that you specify in the data-target of your collapsed button.  It'll then take that UL and place it "under" the button in mobile version.  Also, make sure that you're loading both the css and js for Bootstrap.

Compare to this working example:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0axkrma/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```